# What is a good X minutes for caching routes before invalidation for Google Directions API?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was thinking of caching routes returned by google directions API into a database and invalidating them after 5 minutes. Is this a good time before needing to contact Google again for the latest routes or is it too high/too low?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a good starting point.

Directions responses may change quickly due to live traffic conditions, which influence routing. 5 minutes sounds like a reasonable generic compromise to serve fresh enough results.

The Google Maps APIs Terms of Use [allow temporary caching for performance reasons up to 30 days](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_5) ([always subject to displaying results on a Google Map](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/place-details#attributions)). Therefore, you may want to let your database refresh less often in some cases. This becomes more of a "cache invalidation" problem then, and one for which I think predicting refresh period will be harder than usual, because it changes over time as well as across regions.

Comment: Can you answer this question too for me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45642278/questions-on-avoid-tollroads-in-google-directions-api

Thanks :)

Comment: Is this still correct? The "terms of use" link above is broken and I can't find anything about it.

Comment: Actually, no, Terms of Service were updated around 2018 and caching is generally no longer allowed, with a few exceptions. See point 3.2.3.(b) in https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/ and the Directions API section in https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms